# asp and javascript message alert doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, asp-classic

here's my code

```
<%
if request.form("Add") = "  Add  " then

        if request.form("txtdistributor") = "" or request.form("sinumber") = "" or request.form("tstdate") = "" or request.form("drnumber") = "" or request.form("drdate") = "" or request.form("receivedby") = "" then
        response.redirect("salesinvoice.asp?userloggedin=" &request.querystring("userloggedin") &"&dist=" &request.QueryString("dist") ) 
        end if


            SQLString = "INSERT INTO salesinvoice (distributor,sidate,sinumber) VALUES ('" & Request.form("txtdistributor") & "','" & Request.Form("tstdate") & "','" & Request.Form("sinumber") &"') "

            set DBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            DBConn.Open Application("dals_ConnectionString")

            DBConn.Execute(SQLString)
            DBConn.Close


            set DBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            DBConn.Open Application("dals_ConnectionString")
            SQLString = "INSERT INTO Delivery_Receipt (Date_Purchase, Receipt_no, Distributor, Received_by, Entry_Date,sinumber) VALUES"
            SQLString = SQLString & "('" & Request.Form("drdate") & "','" & Request.Form("drnumber") & "', '" & Request.Form("txtdistributor")& "','" & Request.Form("receivedby") & "','" & now() & "','" & request.Form("sinumber") & "')"

            DBConn.Execute(SQLString)
            DBConn.Close



response.Redirect("salesinvoice.asp?userloggedin=" &request.QueryString("userloggedin") &"&dist=" &request.QueryString("dist"))

end if
%>


<!-- Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateform()
{
    if (document.frm.txtdistributor.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input distributor');
    document.frm.txtdistributor.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if (document.frm.txtdistributor.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input distributor');
    document.frm.txtdistributor.focus();
    return false;
    }   
    if (document.frm.sinumber.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input sales invoice number');
    document.frm.sinumber.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if (document.frm.tstdate.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input sales invoice date');
    document.frm.tstdate.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if (document.frm.drnumber.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input Delivery Receipt Number');
    document.frm.drnumber.focus();
    return false;
    }   
    if (document.frm.drdate.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input Delivery Receipt');
    document.frm.drdate.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if (document.frm.receivedby.value == '')
    {
    alert('Please input requestor');
    document.frm.receivedby.focus();
    return false;
    }
return true;
}
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sales Invoice</title>
    </head>
<body>

<!--#include file="header.asp"-->
<form name="frm" id="frm" action="salesinvoice.asp?userloggedin=<%=request.QueryString("userloggedin")%>&dist=<%=request.QueryString("dist")%>" method="post" onSubmit="return validateform();">

<link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar_date_picker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var cdp1 = new CalendarDatePicker();
 var props = {
    debug :         true,
    excludeDays :       [6,0,1],
    excludeDates :      ['20081225','20081226','20091225','20091226'],
    minimumFutureDate : 5,
    formatDate :        '%m-%d-%y'
    };
 var cdp2 = new CalendarDatePicker(props);
 props.formatDate = '%d-%m-%y';
 var cdp3 = new CalendarDatePicker(props);
 cdp3.endYear = cdp3.startYear + 1;
 </script>

<table width="900" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="200">Distributor</td>
        <td>

    <%if request.querystring("dist") <> "yes" then%>

        <select name="txtdistributor"  style="width:260;">
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
         <%
            strsql = "select Distinct(Distributor) from salesinvoice"
            set rsdist = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
            rsdist.open strsql,application("dals_connectionstring")

            while not rsdist.eof
         %> 

            <option value="<%=rsdist("distributor")%>"><%=rsdist("distributor")%></option>

        <%
        rsdist.movenext
        wend

        rsdist.close
        set rsdist = nothing
        %>
    </select>&nbsp;<a href="salesinvoice.asp?UserLoggedIn=<%=request.QueryString("UserLoggedIn")%>&dist=yes">Add New Distributor</a>
    <%end if%>

    <%if request.querystring("dist") <> "no" then%>
        <input type="text" size="38" name="txtdistributor" id="txtdistributor">&nbsp;<a href="salesinvoice.asp?UserLoggedIn=<%=request.QueryString("UserLoggedIn")%>&dist=no">[ - ]</a>   
    <%end if%>

        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SI Number</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sinumber" id="sinumber"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SI Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tstdate" id="txtdate" readonly>&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="cdp1.showCalendar(this, 'txtdate'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.png" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor:hand;" title="Calendar"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DR Number</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="drnumber" id="drnumber"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DR date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="drdate" id="drdate" readonly>&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="cdp1.showCalendar(this, 'drdate'); return false;"><img src="images/calendar.png" border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor:hand;" title="Calendar"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Received by</td>
        <td>
        <!--<input type="text" name="receivedby" id="receivedby">-->
        <select name="receivedby" id="receivedby">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <%
            strsql = "select first_name,last_name from sysadusers"
            set rsname = server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
            rsname.open strsql,application("dals_connectionstring")

            while not rsname.eof
            %>
                <option value="<%=rsname("first_name")%>, <%=rsname("last_name")%>"><%=rsname("first_name")%>, <%=rsname("last_name")%></option>
            <%
            rsname.movenext
            wend

            rsname.close
            %>

        </select>
```

Comment: SQL injection attack, anyone?

Comment: how sir can you teach me thanks

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler that is separate issue in this case, the issue here is on scripting

Answer (score 0):

You might have runtime error in the validation function, for example when the form does not contain the `txtdistributor` drop down.

For the sake of debugging, change the function to this only:

```
function validateform() {
   alert("validation started");
   var oDDL = document.frm.txtdistributor;
   if (oDDL) {
      if (oDDL.value == '') {
         alert('Please input distributor');
         oDDL.focus();
      }
   } else {
      alert("form does not contain txtdistributor");
   }
   alert("validation ended");

   return false;
}
```

If this works, apply the same logic for the rest of the fields and remove the debug messages.